# Checkbox not setChecked not smoothly

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox, smoothing

I have a `CheckBox` that I set `OnCheckedChangeListener` for it and in the `onCheckedChange` method I have heavy code. When I want to set `Checkbox.checked` it gets checked with a little delay. I want it to set checked smooth with no delay I used post and runnable in `onCheckedChange` method but it wasn't changed.

Comment: post your code .............

Answer (score 0):

Try to use threads , I think it'll help

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run(){        
            // Your heavy code
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setOnClickListener**, in **onClick** method write your code..
To get the status of checkbox, you can use **isChecked()** method which returns boolean value.

```
c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.checkboxid:

                    if (checked) {
                        //true case
                    } else {
                        //false case
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread and post on View didn't help,but postDelayed helped me

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   final int id = buttonView.getId();


    buttonView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           //hard code


            }


        }
    },400);
```

}